# Загрузка изображения с помощью AJAX без JQuery

Tags: ajax, изображения, загрузка

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста реализовать(или дать ссылку где есть способ реализации) загрузки изображений на сервер(с дальнейшей обработкой с помощью PHP) с помощью AJAX, без использования библиотеки JQuery.

Comment: Вот так попробуйте https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-onprogress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ - это встроенный объект браузера XMLHttpRequest.

```
img = document.getElementById('id of input with type file');
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send(img.value);
```

скорей всего не заработает, но идея такая

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp
https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898